# How to post from okhttp3 with encoding params

Tags: android, encoding, okhttp

How to post from okhttp3 with encoding params like that in AndroidHttpClient:

```
List<NameValuePair> values..

((HttpPost) request).setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values, "windows-1251"))
```

i trying

```
    FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
    for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : values) {
        formBuilder.add(nameValuePair.getName(), nameValuePair.getValue());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "post: " + url);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .addHeader( "Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=windows-1251")
            .url(url)
            .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
            .post(formBuilder.build())
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try use `public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN
          = MediaType.parse("text/plain; windows-1251");` like in [okhttp wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)

```
public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN
      = MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8");

  private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public void run() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("README.md");

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.github.com/markdown/raw")
        .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, file))
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
```